GND Copper pour on TOP/BOTTOM?
If I open the PCB of a Texas Instruments ControlCard I notice they did not add a copper pour plane on the top and the bottom. I know there is a GND plane below, but in my understanding, more ground is better.
Is there any reason for not doing it by default?



See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115717/layout-of-4-layer-pcb-pour/115746#115746 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/multi-layer-board-copper-pour/26287#26287 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79965/is-it-good-to-ground-the-polygon-plane-on-the-routing-layer/153918#153918 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/548556/4-layer-pcb-standard-stackup-grounding

Are you sure there is no ground pour on top/bottom, or there is but it just is not drawn to see better?

@Justme, I believe you are right, and the pour polygon is removed for clarity.

@Justme If this is it, it looks like no: https://www.ti.com/tool/TMDSCNCD28379D
